# Three way cross matching csv and pulling/printing data in python

Tags: python, regex, csv, python-2.7, match

I'm trying to do a three way cross-match matching 3 elements between a text file and a CSV and as a result of each match we would be calling/getting certain elements to be appended to a string...

Text file item's should be split by  two new lines `/n/n`

`Textfile item line 1` should be matching up to a line(s) in `CSV Element 2`
`Textfile item line 2` should be matching up to a line(s) in `CSV Element 1`

If both matches are a success then it needs to match the students name, in the first case "Tommy" with `CSV Element 9`

Once all three variables are matched we know what line CSV line we are matched on, now from this we need to record `CSV Element 10`, we also need to find "Data 2" from the textfile item

We need to then all again for the next few names, in our first example it's Jim, Elz M and Ben

At the end of running the script I should be able to do something like:

```
print Match1[0], Match3[0], Match1[0], Data1[0], Data2[0]
print Match1[1], Match3[1], Match1[1], Data1[1]
print Match1[2], Match3[2], Match1[2], Data1[2]
```

Which would output:

```
DMATCH1 MData (N/A) Tommy 55 Data2 $10.40
DMATCH1 MData (N/A) Jim 52
DMATCH1 MData (N/A) Elz M 22
```

My CSV looks like:

```
MATCH1,MATCH2,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,MATCH3,DATA,TITLE,TITLE
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Tommy,55,data,data
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Ben,54,data,data
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Jim,52,data,data
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Elz M,22,data,data
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,James Smith,15,data,data
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,Jessica Long,224,data,data
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,Mike,62,data,data
DMATCH3,Mdata,data,data,data,data,data,data,Joe Reane,66,data,data
DMATCH3,Mdata,data,data,data,data,data,data,Peter Jones,256,data,data
DMATCH3,Mdata,data,data,data,data,data,data,Lesley Lope,5226,data,data
```

My text file consists of:

```
MData (N/A)
DMATCH1
3 Tommy 144512/23332
1 Jim 90000/222311
1 Elz M 90000/222311
1 Ben 90000/222311
Data $50.90
Data2 $10.40
Data3 $20.20


MData (B/B) 
DMATCH2
4 James Smith 2333/114441
4 Mike 90000/222311
4 Jessica Long 2333/114441
Data $50.90
Data2 $5.44


Mdata
DMATCH3
5 Joe Reane 0/0
5 Peter Jones 90000/222311
Data $10.91
Data2 $420.00
Data3 $210.00
```

**If it makes it easier I could modify the text file so it is also in csv format**

Example:

```
MData (N/A),DMATCH1,3 Tommy 144512/23332,1 Jim 90000/222311,1 Elz M 90000/222311,   1 Ben 90000/222311,Data $50.90,Data2 $10.40,Data3 $20.20
```

Comment: It **might** be better to import this into SQLite as separate tables and perform joins there instead.  This is pretty convoluted and complex to try in Python.

Comment: @Makoto I thought someone would mention using SQL to do it, but unfortunately I can't use SQL unless python can easy control and use SQLLite to fully automate it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my attempt:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

# Nested defaultdict for data structure
def make_map():
    def make_map_dict():
        return defaultdict(dict)
    return defaultdict(make_map_dict)

# Read in the data
with open('/path/to/your/txt_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt_data = [map(str.strip, x.split('\n')) for x in map(str.strip, f.read().split('\n\n')) if x]

with open('/path/to/your/csv_file.csv', 'r') as f:
    header = f.readline()
    csv_data = [map(str.strip, x.split(',')) for x in map(str.strip, f.read().split('\n')) if x]

# Generate a mapping dictionaries
txt_map = defaultdict(make_map)
csv_map = defaultdict(make_map)

# Regex matches
name_re = re.compile(r'^(\d+) +(\w+(?: \w+)*) +(\d+/\d+)$')
data_re = re.compile(r'^(Data(?:\d+)?) +(\$\d+(?:\.\d{2})?)$')

# Make txt mapping
for datapoint in txt_data:
    names = [name_re.match(x).group(2) for x in datapoint[2:] if name_re.match(x)]
    data = {data_re.match(x).group(1): data_re.match(x).group(2) for x in datapoint[2:] if data_re.match(x)}
    for name in names:
        txt_map[datapoint[1]][datapoint[0]][name] = data

# Make csv mapping
for datapoint in csv_data:
    csv_map[datapoint[0]][datapoint[1]][datapoint[8]] = [datapoint[9]]

# Merge maps
final_map = defaultdict(make_map)
for x in txt_map:
    for y in txt_map[x]:
        for z in txt_map[x][y]:
            if csv_map[x][y][z] is not None:
                final_map[x][y][z] = csv_map[x][y][z] + [txt_map[x][y][z]]

# You now have final_map to do with what you will
```

This leaves you with a nested data structure. You could flatten and `zip` it if needed. Hope it helps!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    txt_data = [map(str.strip, x.split('\n')) for x in map(str.strip, f.readall().split('\n\n')) if x]
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'readall'

Any ideas?